# Login with facebook - Insecure Login Blocked

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I know that this question have been asked before, but my scenario is a bit different. I'm trying to implement login with facebook feature into my website, **which has SSL**, but when I attempt to login I get an error message:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://

Ideas?

Comment: Then you probably have not specified this correctly in your app settings somewhere, or your system creates a login dialog URL with incorrect parameters (such as redirect_uri still pointing to an HTTP URL perhaps.)

Comment: @CBroe Valid OAuth Redirect URIs setting is set to `https://www.my-domain.com/`

Comment: Great, but apparently not the issue ... (This could probably go a bit quicker without fake-example-URLs-because-project-so-secret ...)

Comment: @CBroe I've also double checked my URI with `Redirect URI Validator` which I've found in Facebook login -> settings and it responded with `This is a valid redirect URI for this application` so I'm guessing it's valid. The domain is `https://www.minfo.lt`

Comment: Also I've been trying this out through `https://www.minfo.lt/test55521`

Comment: So, exactly as I suspected ... your login dialog call includes `redirect_uri=http://www.minfo.lt/social/facebook/callback`

Comment: Hmm ok I'll try to dig into that, sorry about that and thanks for Your help :)

Answer (score 3):

This solution was tested on a django application using *Facebook OAuth*

**NOTE**

- my site already had SSL and is accessible via https

But when trying to login using Facebook OAuth i get the above error (**Insecure Login Blocked**)

**My Solution**

all i had to do was to set ( this configuration is done within application setting :: `settings.py` )

*ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'*

[helpful link](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1994)

which literally means

`use *https* instead of the default *http* when trying to login using social account e.g Facebook`

Then i also set **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** on facebook login settings to `https://redirect_url.com`

**For non django application**

If you're not using django, i believe there should be a base configuration file, where all your configurations for the application are done (it might be same file where you've configured your application to use social authentication).

Whatever library you're using to enforce social authentication, search for how you can allow redirect to be done via https instead of the default http and then add it to your application's configuration file.

I hope this helps someone save some time